# Reemplazar punto por coma en Python 3

Tags: python

Hola tengo una lista de decimales que convertí a String, para poder cambiar los puntos por comas. Pero con "replace" no me permite realizar el cambio, lo estoy haciendo de esta forma:

```
   for i in range(len(UCL)): #UCL de corte
      UCL[i].replace(".",",")
      print(UCL[i])
```

La lista originl UCL es de la forma:

```
    ['2.363636368', '2.17391304', '3.875', '2.282828286', '2.383838386', '2.616161618', '2.363636368', '4.85', '4.75', '2.282828289', '2.616161618', '0.666666666', '3.0', '3.272727272', '2.434343439', '0.666666666', '0.666666666', '2.538461538', '0.666666666', '3.875', '2.616161618', '2.393939396', '0.666666666', '0.666666666', '0.666666666', '0.666666666', '2.383838384']
```

Mi idea es imprimir lo mismo pero cambiando los puntos por comas dentro de cada string de la lista UCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL problema es que `str` es inmutable y `replace` por tanto retorna una copia de la cadena (no puede modificar la cadena original). Puedes crear una nueva lista usando compresión de listas con:

```
nueva_UCL = [c.replace('.', ',') for c in UCL]
```

Si prefieres usar un `for` normal y modificar la lista original debes hacer:

```
for i in range(len(UCL)):
    UCL[i] = UCL[i].replace(".", ",")
```

---

Supongo que quieres modificar la lista además de imprimirla. Si solo quisieras imprimir usando comas, sin modificar la lista original, podrias hacer (en Python 3):

```
print(*(c.replace(".", ",") for c in UCL), sep='\n')
```

O para Python 2/Python3:

```
for c in UCL:
    print(c.replace(".", ","))
```

Answer (score 1):

Jorge, en Python las cadenas como varios otros objetos son inmutables, hacer esto:

```
s = "1.4"
print(s.replace(".",","))
print(s)
```

Va a retornarte esto:

```
1,4
1.4
```

Con esto confirmamos que `s` sigue valiendo "1.4". Lo que se debe hacer es generar una nueva cadena mediante la asignación:

```
s = s.replace(".",",")
print(s)
```

Y ahora sí

```
1,4
```

En tu ejemplo debieras hacer lo siguiente:

```
UCL[i] = UCL[i].replace(".",",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo use este y si me sirvio:

`(tudato.replace(".",',') or :)`

despues del replace mencionas lo que quieres reemplzar, despues por lo que quieres que aparezca y el `or` significa o cambias `.` o `:` por una `,`

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona:

```
df["Close"] = df["Close"].str.replace(".", ",")
```